# Как выкинуть модуль QML при компиляции QT из исходников?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, build

Компилирую Qt из исходников без gui. То есть при конфигурации указал флаг `-no-gui`. Никакого флага вроде `-no-qml` не нашел, все, что есть `-no-qml-debug`. Вот полный перечень конфигурации:

> ./configure -prefix /home/asianirish/Qt-custom/qt-embedded-5.7 -debug
>   -static -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -qt-zlib -c++std c++11 -no-libpng -no-libjpeg -no-sql-sqlite2 -no-sql-psql -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-odbc -no-sql-oci -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-db2 -no-qml-debug -no-widgets -no-gui -no-opengl -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license -v

На уровне выполнения **make** сыпет:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: gui
Makefile:49: recipe for target 'sub-calculator-qml-make_first' failed
make[3]: *** [sub-calculator-qml-make_first] Error 3
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtscxml/examples/scxml'
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'sub-scxml-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-scxml-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtscxml/examples'
Makefile:96: recipe for target 'sub-examples-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-examples-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtscxml'
Makefile:355: recipe for target 'module-qtscxml-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtscxml-make_first] Error 2
```

То есть он выкинул модуль gui, но qml оставил и теперь qml требует gui для собственной работы. Ясно, что этот экзампл `examples/scxml` ни к чему не сдался, но все же **сабж**.

Comment: Не решается ли это как то просто, типа ```QT -= quick``` ?

Comment: @isnullxbh куда этот `quick` вписать/указать?

Comment: В Ваш .pro файл.

Comment: А где/чем собираете ?

Comment: @isnullxbh скачал исходники Qt, выполнил `./configure` (с параметрами, указанными в вопросе) и далее `make`. Среди ключей конфигурации каких-либо упоминаний `quick` не обнаружил

Comment: [тут](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57624/is-it-possible-to-build-qt-5-without-qml) посмотрите, там есть готовая команда, которая сразу пачку модулей отрежет. Хотя желание, конечно, странное.

Comment: @ixSci да да, спасибо, как раз сейчас это осуществляю )) Посмотрим, высипит ли еще что-нибудь. А что же тут странного?? )

Comment: А зачем исключать модули из сборки? Просто не подключайте в своём коде те, что не нужны. Чем бороться с этой кучей зависимостей, как мне кажется, проще использовать полную версию.

Comment: @ixSci должно выполняться на Arm без графики. Сейчас, по вашему совету, пустил мейка без `no-gui` - стал ругаться на отстутсвия заголовка от png (`src/sfnt/pngshim.c:31:17: fatal error: png.h:`). Сейчас попробую пустить без `-no-libpng -no-libjpeg`, но не исключено, что тогда еще что-нибудь нового захочет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достиг успеха следующей конфигурацией:

> ./configure -prefix /home/asianirish/Qt-custom/qt-embedded-openssl-5.7
>   -debug -static -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtsensors -skip qttools -skip qtwebsockets -skip
>   qtwinextras -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -nomake examples
>   -qt-zlib -c++std c++11 -no-sql-sqlite2 -no-sql-psql -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-odbc -no-sql-oci -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-db2 -no-opengl -sysroot /home/asianirish/olimex/ -opensource -confirm-license -v

То есть, добавил `gui` (также потребовалось включить `libjpeg` and `libpng`). Огромное спасибо @ixSci за ценный совет!

Так же включил флаг `-sysroot` для доступности некоторых библиотек.

Все компилируется с Qt и выполняется на Арме. Спасибо всем, кто комментировал вопрос!